# invalid src prop, hostname not configured

Tags: reactjs, next.js

This is the error I am getting. I am using Next/auth. I am trying to display the user profiles who logged in.
[image]

i tried to fix this:

[image]

[image]

Changed next config to:
[image]

Comment: Try restarting your server if you just added the domains array.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar Already did that

Comment: I see. Consider pasting code as plain text and not images (this is why someone downvoted you, I think).